# java.lang.SecurityException: Access not allowed for content://android.media.tv/watched_program

Tags: android, android-securityexception

I have compiled the sample TV Input for the STB platform. As per the readme under
https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-sample-inputs
when running live channels app, i am observing following exceptions and app is failing to launch

> /ActivityManager( 2708): Start proc 3672:com.google.android.tv/u0a47
>   for service com.google.android.tv/.recommendation.NotificationService
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 3462): Writing exception to parcel E/DatabaseUtils(
>   3462): java.lang.SecurityException: Access not allowed for
>   content://android.media.tv/watched_program

The services RichTv and Simple are running in background.
How to fix this exception?

Answer (score 0):

I believe from that error you may need to add two permissions to your manifest:

```
<!-- Required to update or read existing channel and program information in TvProvider. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.tv.permission.READ_EPG_DATA" />
<!-- Required to update channel and program information in TvProvider. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.tv.permission.WRITE_EPG_DATA" />
```

If you need more help you can look at my project: http://github.com/fleker/cumulustv

Comment: I have these permission declared in manifest but still facing this issue.